# Code works with CSS but not with style defined in JS

Tags: javascript, html

In an example I work with, the following is defined:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
```

As I can only have JS, I tried to define it in the code and remove the HTML, like this:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 50, "position","absolute","width","28px","height","28px","background","lightsteelblue","font", "12px sans-serif","text-align","center","pointer-events","none","border-radius","0px");
```

But now the following code stops working, I cannot figure out why.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(d.date + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("right", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")        
                .style("down", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");   
            })
```

Comment: Your assignment to div is through numerous function calls, any one of which may be incorrect, try splitting it up and include some error handling.

Comment: @SPlatten The thing is, it works fine when I put the CSS definition of tooltip back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
  .attr("style", " position: absolute; ... pointer-events: none;")
```

Answer (score 0):

d3.style doesn't support the syntax you're trying. Try this:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style({   
        "position": "absolute",      
        "text-align": "center",       
        "width": "60px",
        "height": "28px",
        "padding": "2px",
        "font": "12px sans-serif",
        "background": "lightsteelblue",
        "border": "0px",
        "border-radius": "8px",
        "pointer-events": "none"
    });
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, I think you meant ',' after each line not ';'

Comment: You're totally correct. I copy pasted the CSS and forgot to swap those semicolons!